# I used the compositor to add blur effects but they are not showing up in my final render image?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I followed a blender tutorial and made the Earth. I have a sun in the background that I added some blur effects to in the compositor. When I rendered my image, the blur effects on the sun don't show up. How do I render the final image from the compositor? Are there settings that I am missing? Here is a screenshot of the composited image above the rendered image.

[image: The top picture is the compositor view. The picture below that is the final rendered view.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are sending the final image to a *Composite* node. The *Viewer* node only displays in the backdrop of the node editor.

[image]